# I imported an excel document i ran it through foreach, now this value need to export to the table on the web browser, or grid view

Tags: mysql, asp.net, c#-4.0

I import my excel file and through `foreach` I pulled the columns that I need, so now I need to show these values ​​in a table on the web browser.

I tried to export this to grid view but without success.

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var doc = new cl23_ispEntities();
            var p = doc.archivebook.ToList();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {

            try
            {
                var database = new cl23_ispEntities();
                //to do check
                //proceeding.filepathdetails = filepath;
                string fileName = "test.xlsx";
                        //insert data from xls to database
                        var pathxls = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(string.Format("{0}", "~/uploads")), fileName);

                        string connectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";", pathxls);

                        string sheetName = "Sheet1";
                        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", sheetName), connectionString);

                        var ds = new DataSet();

                        adapter.Fill(ds, "ExcelTable");

                        DataTable dtable = ds.Tables["ExcelTable"];

                foreach (DataRow row in dtable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
                {
                    string barkod = row[3].ToString() + " " + row[4].ToString() + " " + row[1].ToString() + " " + row[6].ToString();

                    izuzimanje x = new izuzimanje();

                    x.barkod = barkod;
                    x.datum = DateTime.Now;
                    x.idstatus = 1;
                    x.tipzahtjeva = 1;

                    database.izuzimanje.Add(x);
                }

                database.SaveChanges();

                var dataexport = database.getIzuzimanje().ToList();

                return View();

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store all the excel info that you need in a object, like 'izuzimanjeList', and then return it to the view, like this:

```
List<Izuzimanje> izuzimanjeList = new List<Izuzimanje>();
 foreach (DataRow row in dtable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
                {
                    string barkod = row[3].ToString() + " " + row[4].ToString() + " " + row[1].ToString() + " " + row[6].ToString();

                    izuzimanje x = new izuzimanje();

                    x.barkod = barkod;
                    x.datum = DateTime.Now;
                    x.idstatus = 1;
                    x.tipzahtjeva = 1;

                    database.izuzimanje.Add(x);
                    izuzimanjeList.Add(x);
                }
                database.SaveChanges();

                var dataexport = database.getIzuzimanje().ToList();

                return View(izuzimanjeList);
```

'That's ok but how to use this values and bind to ,example in my case on about page section, how to display them in the table on the browser or in the excel file that would be available on the website'